Understanding parametric types and their super-types in Julia
I want to understand the type system of the Julia language. The following situation I find confusing:
Consider the chain of sub/super-types
Rational{Int64} <: Rational <: Real <: Number <: Any

which (in my mind) corresponds to a path in the type tree starting at the concrete type Rational{Int64} and going up to the top. Now, if I call supertype(Rational) I get Real as expected. However, when I call supertype(Rational{Int64}) I get Real, too. The supertype function seems to 'jump' over Rational. This seems very counter-intuitive to me.
Can anyone explain this behaviour?

In Julia, only DataTypes participate in inheritance. If a type does not have all of its generic type parameters specified, as with Rational (short for Rational{T} where T<:Integer), then it is not a DataType but a UnionAll, and since a UnionAll is not actually a type, it does not participate in inheritance.
julia> Rational === Rational{T} where T<:Integer
true

julia> typeof.((Rational{Int}, Rational, Real))
(DataType, UnionAll, DataType)


Your intuition is correct, but Julia does not define the "type tree" how you have in your question. In particular, Rational is not ever defined independent of Rational{Int}. Below is the definition for the type, as of 1.10.5, and also as found here: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/rational.jl.

"""
    Rational{T<:Integer} <: Real

Rational number type, with numerator and denominator of type `T`.
Rationals are checked for overflow.
"""
struct Rational{T<:Integer} <: Real
    num::T
    den::T

    # Unexported inner constructor of Rational that bypasses all checks
    global unsafe_rational(::Type{T}, num, den) where {T} = new{T}(num, den)
end

...


So, essentially, Rational is a type that holds 2 integers in it, and you can limit those integers to different sizes by providing an optional type T. If unspecified, Rational defaults, and is equivalent, to Rational{Int64}. So, the type tree, expanding Rational, is essentially:
Rational{IntXX} <: Real <: Number <: Any
where IntXX refers to any valid Integer type.
